# HAProxy regex file extension

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, haproxy

I have two applications that interface with each other. The one application has been upgraded and the requested url in the new version is not valid on the second application. I am attempting to put HAProxy in between the applications to resolve this issue. I am having trouble coming up with a working regex expression to resolve the issue.

Requested url: https://www.example.com/certs/download
Correct url I need to change this to: https://www.example.com/certs/download.zip

how can I add .zip to the request if it is for /certs/download and no other requests. most of the examples I find are a replace for mid string and seem to not work for the very and of the query. Regex is also over my head and new to me. It seems that the exact haproxy implementation is different as haproxy config examples I find error out in all online regex checkers.

Answer (score 1):

With HAProxy >= 1.6, you can just add the like this:

```
http-request set-path %[path].zip if { path /certs/download }
```

That way, the extension is only added if the ACL matches. For more details about how to use the various `http-request` rules, please have a look at the [documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-http-request).